# how to hide the virtual keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, virtual, hide

I don't want to show the virtual keyboard.

I tried the below method but it doesn't make any difference.

```
InputMethodManager imm =     InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(enter_count.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

enter_count is my edit text
I have tried reading up on the InputMethod Manager but can't follow it.

I can set the input type of my edit text called enter_count as follows

```
enter_count.setInputType( InputType.TYPE_NULL );
```

but then I can't specify to only accept numeric input

Can you please give me a reasonable solution to simply not show the virtual keyboard without losing the ability to only accept numeric input on the physical keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_hello);

editText.setKeyListener(new NumberKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_NULL;
    }

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use this in your AndroidManifest.xml file

So add

**android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"**

But with that your keyboard will always be hidden in that Activity.

Wouter

Comment: I tried your suggestion and 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
as well but neither made any difference

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this in the Activity tag of your manifest?
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your`SendData()` function

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textEntered.getWindowToken(),0);
```

OR use this

```
InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

this work :)