# Way to hide softkeypad provided not effecting the features of the edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, hide, soft-keyboard

I have hidden soft keypad because I have custom keypad on the app. When the edittext is clicked, soft keypad shouldn't pop up. So, I have tried so many ways from the sources, but nothing worked except the `editText.setFocusable(false);` . But now the problem is edittext is not getting highlighted when I clicked it and even cursor is not visible. I have tried using `InputManager`, `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden` in the manifest and referred many like [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997225/how-to-hide-android-soft-keyboard-on-edittext) , [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1) etc., but these techniques atleast don't even hide the soft keypad on my app. Finally I got this through setFocusable, but there is a highlighting problem and cursor invisible problem and even `requestFocus()` in the onClickListener didn't work. Can someone give exact solution for this problem? Code snippet is appreciated.

Comment: I think this will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803193/android-disable-soft-keyboard-at-all-edittexts

Comment: I used `.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL)` and have your problem. call me if you found the solution.

Comment: @Rahul I have referred this too previously. As you can see at the end, the OP in that link didn't get the output that he wanted with those answers and Neither did I after trying those.

Comment: @breceivemail Okay. Will let you know if I found the solution. You are completely disabling the edittext by TYPE_NULL so that in the edittext, nothing can be entered.

Comment: i had posted solution there check it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994732/how-to-hide-the-virtual-keyboard/21878009#21878009

Comment: The Question is a duplicate of [Android Hide Soft Keyboard from EditText while not losing cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13586354/7550472). The solution for this is to set the flag `textIsSelectable` in EditText to **true**. For more details, check the detailed answer here at : [http://stackoverflow.com/a/42180201/7550472](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42180201/7550472)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Hide Soft Keyboard from EditText while not losing cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586354/android-hide-soft-keyboard-from-edittext-while-not-losing-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one in activity class

```
getwindow().setsoftInputMode(winowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

This one is avoiding of soft key pad

Comment: This doesn't work in my case, if you see the links provided above. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFomWindow( edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

please use this in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"         
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score 1):

You ddont need to add any method in menifist. just add this code.. It will automaticlly hide when you click on button to get value.

Want to hide softkeyboard use this code in your click listener method.

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFomWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(),0);

i hope this code work fine.

Answer (score 1):

how about if you editText.setOnTouchListener and when you create the new OnTouchListener do nothing something like:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

});
```